# How can I get the user input from a HTML form and store it in an existing JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form and I want to get the user input and store it as an array in a new variable in JavsScript.

Here is my form:

```
  <form id="contractFormForm">
      Contract Reference: <br>
      <input type="text" name="contractref" id="contractref"> <br>
      Grower Reference: <br>
      <input type="text" name="growerref" id="growerref"> <br>
       Main Group: <br>
      <input type="text" name="maingroup" id="maingroup"> <br>        
       Item: <br>
      <input type="text" name="item" id="item"> <br>  
       Quantity Ordered: <br>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"> <br>
      Total Price for Order: <br>
      <input type="text" name="totalprice" id="totalprice"> <br>          
      Delivery Date: <br>
      <input type="text" name="date" id="date"> <br> <br>  
      <input type="button" value="Add new contract" onclick="readData();"/>
  </form>
```

I want to get the values for each form item and create a new contract with it, in the structure of:

```
 var contractX = new Contract(0, "", "", "", 000, "£000", "00/00/00");
GC.growerContracts.push(contract1);
```

This new contract then gets pushed into the following:

```
var GC = { growerContracts: [] };

function Contract(ref, grower, group, item, quantity, price, delivery) {
    this.contract_ref = ("gc" + ref);
    this.grower_ref = grower;
    this.main_group = group;
    this.sub_group = item;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.total_price = price;
    this.delivery_date = delivery;
}
```

Currently I manually create the contracts as follows:

```
var contract1 = new Contract(1, "gr1", "seed", "wheat", 500, "£1234", "01/03/15");
GC.growerContracts.push(contract1);

var contract2 = new Contract(2, "gr2", "seed", "grass", 1250, "£3456", "10/04/15");
GC.growerContracts.push(contract2);
```

These are then displayed as a table on the page. The code for the table is:

```
function addTable(growerContracts) {
  var contractTable = document.createElement("TABLE");
  contractTable.setAttribute("id", "contractTable");
  document.body.appendChild(contractTable);

  for (var i = 0; i < growerContracts.length; i++) {
    var contract = growerContracts[i];
    var row = document.createElement("TR");

    var contractRefCell = document.createElement("TD");

    var growerRefCell = document.createElement("TD");

    var groupCell = document.createElement("TD"); 

    var itemCell = document.createElement("TD"); 

     var quantityCell = document.createElement("TD");

    var priceCell = document.createElement("TD");

    var deliveryCell = document.createElement("TD");

    row.appendChild(contractRefCell);
    row.appendChild(growerRefCell);
    row.appendChild(groupCell);
    row.appendChild(itemCell);
    row.appendChild(quantityCell);
    row.appendChild(priceCell);
    row.appendChild(deliveryCell);

    var contractRef = document.createTextNode(contract.contract_ref);

     var growerRef = document.createTextNode(contract.grower_ref);

     var group = document.createTextNode(contract.main_group);

    var item = document.createTextNode(contract.sub_group);

      var quantity = document.createTextNode(contract.quantity);

      var price = document.createTextNode(contract.total_price);

      var delivery = document.createTextNode(contract.delivery_date);

    contractRefCell.appendChild(contractRef);
    growerRefCell.appendChild(growerRef);
    groupCell.appendChild(group);
    itemCell.appendChild(item);    
    quantityCell.appendChild(quantity);
    priceCell.appendChild(price);  
    deliveryCell.appendChild(delivery); 

    contractTable.appendChild(row);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  addTable(GC.growerContracts)
});
```

This is my current attempt at a readData function - Loads of errors: reference errors, It's always going to override contract5 ...

```
function readData() {

var contract5 = new Contract(ref, grower, group, item, quantity, price, delivery);

contract5.ref = document.getElementById("contractref");
contract5.grower = document.getElementById("growerref");
contract5.group = document.getElementById("maingroup");
contract5.item = document.getElementById("item");
contract5.quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
contract5.price = document.getElementById("totalprice");
contract5.delivery = document.getElementById("date");       

GC.growerContracts.push(contract5);

console.log(contract5);

}
```

So... On the click of the button from the form, I want to create a new contract with the form values as the values of the contract.

Note; I want to be able to create several contracts so that these can be displayed in the table.

Hope this makes sense. Not quite sure how to articulate my problem but please ask if you are unsure with what I mean and I will try to expand...

Comment: Frameworks exist to help you out here.  JQuery, KnockoutJS etc..  please indicate if you are happy to use (or already do use a framework) because I would not attempt this sort of thing without one.

Comment: oh ok, thanks. I'm happy to try and use a framework then. (preferably the easier one as I'm not a very confident coder) I don't use any currently.

Comment: what are the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a framework, I can suggest something like knockout JS.

http://www.knockoutjs.com

The purpose of this framework is to separate your JavaScript model (in this case your Contact objects) from the presentation.  Your code contains a lot of HTML manipulation which can be offloaded into knockout and it will provide this functionality for you using data binding.

E.g it takes a model, and it takes a view (of HTML with data binding configuration) and binds them together to create your output.  When the model changes, the view is updated automatically, and when fields change on the view, the model is updated automatically.

This two way binding gives you clear separation of concerns and clean code that does not contain (or should not contain) any JavaScript which directly modifies the HTML document (e.g document.getElementById / document.createElement etc...)

Can I suggest you read the knockout js link, and to put it into context have a look at this fiddle that demonstrates the basic behavior you are after by using KnockoutJS.

http://jsfiddle.net/tt0L6zm0/2/

The View Model:

```
var vm = {
    items: ko.observableArray([]),
    contactReference: ko.observable(),
    growerReference: ko.observable(),
    mainGroup: ko.observable(),
    item: ko.observable(),
    quantityOrdered: ko.observable(),
    totalPrice: ko.observable(),
    deliveryDate: ko.observable(),
    addItem: function () {
    this.items.push({
        contactReference: this.contactReference(),
        growerReference: this.growerReference(),
        mainGroup: this.mainGroup(),
        item: this.item(),
        quantityOrdered: this.quantityOrdered(),
        totalPrice: this.totalPrice(),
        deliveryDate: this.deliveryDate()
    });
   }
 }

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

The view:

```
<form id="contractFormForm">Contract Reference:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactReference">

    <br/>Grower Reference:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: growerReference">

    <br/>Main Group:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: mainGroup">

    <br/>Item:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: item">
    <br/>Quantity Ordered:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: quantityOrdered">

    <br/>Total Price for Order:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: totalPrice">

    <br/>Delivery Date:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: deliveryDate">

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Add new contract" data-bind="click: addItem" />
</form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact Reference</td>
            <td>Grower Reference</td>
            <td>Main Group</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Quantity Ordered</td>
            <td>Total Price for Order</td>
            <td>Delivery Date</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind=" text: contactReference "></td>
            <td data-bind="text: growerReference "></td>
            <td data-bind="text: mainGroup "></td>
            <td data-bind="text: item "></td>
            <td data-bind="text: quantityOrdered "></td>
            <td data-bind="text: totalPrice "></td>
            <td data-bind="text: deliveryDate "></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This may look a little unfamiliar if you are used to operating directly with the DOM, but it will simplify your client side browser development significantly.

In more detail:

You view model contains knockout objects called "observables" these are basically objects that contain the value for your model, including lists of objects (observableArray). They also raise changed events when their values change.

Your view, then binds to these observables, e.g from the textbox

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: contactReference">
```

The **data-bind** attribute contains the binding configuration for knockout, in this example its telling knockout to bind the value of the textbox to the **contactReference** observable.  This means any text changes to this control get written into the observable, and then the observable notifies other components it has changed.  Vice-Versa, any changes to the model through JavaScript has the effect of updating the TextBox value in the UI, they are effectively bound together

Fields can also contain events, e.g the button contains a click binding which invokes a method on the view model

```
<input type="button" value="Add new contract" data-bind="click: addItem" />
```

This invokes the **addItem** method on the view model which is responsible for putting a new item into the array (which automatically notifies the view it has changed):

```
addItem: function () {
    this.items.push({
        contactReference: this.contactReference(),
        growerReference: this.growerReference(),
        mainGroup: this.mainGroup(),
        item: this.item(),
        quantityOrdered: this.quantityOrdered(),
        totalPrice: this.totalPrice(),
        deliveryDate: this.deliveryDate()
    });
```

This array is then bound into the table by using the **foreach** binding:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
```

Which basically loops over each item in the observableArray and builds the user interface.

All of this is initialized at page load using

```
ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

Which binds the view model, and the view together.

The architectural pattern in use here is MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) and is described at a higher level here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel